# Woocommerce products listing by category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want there should be list of products category on my product listing page. And my Product listing will update according to that category list.
Check this png you will understand better.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jch15ohmi4k7zq/TY-Fountain_ProductMain_V2.png?dl=0

Any plugin or code help please? This plugin is close one but issue is this that there are no pagination.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-tabbed-category-product-listing/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce has product archives built into it.  All you have to do is link to the domain url with /product-category/category-slug/ on the end.  Replace category-slug with the slug of any specific product category.